# why my function is not working for except block?

Tags: python, function, try-except

While putting the `def clockPrint()` function in try-except, try block is working fine but except block is not working (printing the statement as output which is in except block)

```
import datetime
try:
    def clockPrint(sentence): 
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(date_time + " : " + sentence)
except TypeError:
    print("Error: Invalid sentence")
```

If I try to call `clockPrint(909)` then according to the logic, it should display "`Error: Invalid sentence`" as an output but it is displaying "`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`" as an output. Any suggestions

Comment: Why is the try _outside_ the function? You'll only catch errors in defining the function, not when it's invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `try` block just does nothing. Define function outside `try` block and just call it from this block.

```
import datetime

def clockPrint(sentence): 
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(date_time + " : " + sentence)

try:
    ...
    clockPrint(sentence)
    ...
except TypeError:
    print("Error: Invalid sentence")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime
def clockPrint(sentence): 
    try:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(date_time + " : " + sentence)
    except TypeError:
        print("Error: Invalid sentence")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
def clockPrint(sentence): 
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    try:
        print(date_time + " : " + sentence)
    except TypeError:
        print("Error: Invalid sentence")
```